# Changing an array inside an object using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form that looks like,

```
const virtual_form = {
    name: 'virtual',
    address_info: [
        {
            name: 'a',
            address: '',
        }
    ]
}
```

I use this as a default state of my hook

```
const [virtualForm, setVirtualForm] = useState(virtual_form)
```

I just providing the user to modify the `address` field.

```
<div className="input-text-wrapper">
    <TextField
        value={virtualForm.address_info.address}
        name="address"
        onChange={(e) => handleAccessInfoChange(e, 'virtual')} />
</div>
```

like above.

However, in my `handleAccessInfoChange`,

```
const handleAccessInfoChange = (e, type) => {
    console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value, type)
    switch (type) {
        case 'virtual':
            setVirtualForm({...virtualForm, address_info[0]: [...virtualForm.address_info, address: value] })
    }
}
```

I am getting a syntax error when I try to change the `virtualForm`. It says `'address' is not defined  no-undef`.

How can I make this to only affect the `address` correctly?

Comment: Is there a reason you have the object with `name` and `address` in an array? The array seems unnecessary

Comment: Because the users should be able to put multiple `address_info`s in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating the object with `address` and `name` as an array, but you cant assign an array with this syntax `[address: value]`. Its looking for a variable called `address` not using it as a key.

Instead, map over it and modify the object at the correct index. I have no way to know which index, so I'll assume `0` as in the question:

```js
setVirtualForm({
  ...virtualForm, 
  address_info: virtualForm.address_info.map((info, i) => {
    if (i == 0) {
      return {
        ...info,
        address: value
      }
    }
    return info
  }
})
```